# Get just inserted id lua-sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, lua

Im trying to get just inserted autoincremented id:

```
local luasql = require "luasql.sqlite3"

dbname = "dbname"
table1 = "table1"
table2 = "table2"

env = luasql.sqlite3()
con = env:connect(dbname)

-- Create table1
res1 = con:execute(string.format("CREATE TABLE '%s' (" ..
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " ..
    "test1 varchar(32), " ..
    "test2 varchar(32))", con:escape(table1)))

-- Create table2
res2 = con:execute(string.format("CREATE TABLE '%s' (" ..
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " ..
    "id_of_row_in_table_1 varchar(32), " ..
    "test2 varchar(32))", con:escape(table2)))

-- Insert data into table1
last_inserted_id = con:execute(string.format("INSERT INTO '%s' ('%s', '%s')", con:escape(table1), 'test1', 'test2', con:escape('1'), con:escape('1')))

print(last_inserted_id) -- unfortunately this do not return just inserted id

-- Insert data into table2
res = con:execute(string.format("INSERT INTO '%s' ('%s', '%s')", con:escape(table2), 'last_inserted_id', 'test2', con:escape(last_inserted_id), con:escape('1')))
```

How to get the last inserted id? I consider an insert function should return just inserted id but it don't.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (I'm using lsqlite3 so adjust accordingly):

```
db = sqlite3.open(':memory:')

db:execute [[
create table xxx(xxx);
insert into xxx values('one');
insert into xxx values('two');
insert into xxx values('three');
]]

sql = [[select last_insert_rowid() as num;]]
for ans in db:nrows(sql) do
  print(ans.num)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it works only in synchronous connection and only for one user. So I think it is not suitable for the real program.